# nth child selector CSS under another class

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, css-selectors

I have a row of in a container a row and container in bootstrap. I am trying to hide the first 2nd child class. for some reason it does not seem to work for me. I have got it to work in the past so Im not sure why it is not working now. I do not want to use Jquery or javascript for the solution. I have added the code I have so far below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
.rounded-image{
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;  
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    /*background-image: url('http://placehold.it/234x150');*/
    background-size: contain; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 118px;
    width:210px;
}

.rounded-image:nth-child(1){
display: none;

}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-12  text-center global-offices">
        <h1>Connect with One of Our Global Offices</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 rounded-image"> </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 Address-lines"> 
         <address>
             <!-- Dublin -->
          <strong>Address</strong><br>
          232 <br>
          10/11 e <br>
          <strong><abbr title="Phone">Phone</abbr></strong> +3530<br>
          <strong><abbr title="Fax">Fax:</abbr></strong> +353
        </address>

      </div>




      <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 rounded-image"> </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6  Address-lines"> 
        <address>
          <!-- Italy -->
          <strong>Address</strong><br>
          Via Marsala I<br>
          Roma<br>
          <strong><abbr title="Phone">Phone</abbr></strong> +370<br>
          <strong><abbr title="Fax">Fax:</abbr></strong> +39
        </address>
      </div>

  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In this example, `<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 rounded-image"> </div>` is the second child of its parent, so if you want to target that, you should use `.rounded-image:nth-child(2)`. By convention, CSS is not zero-indexed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selector `.rounded-image:nth-child(1)` actually means "the element with `rounded-image` class that is the first child of its parent in the same time". In general, combining selectors (like `tag.class` or `.class:pseudo-class`) means the AND condition for these selectors.

The CSS Selectors Level 4 introduced the `:nth-child(An + B of ...)` syntax, which allows to express "the 1st element with given class" condition as `:nth-child(1 of .rounded-image)`. Unfortunately, it works currently only in Safari.

The only way to solve your problem with currently supported CSS (without relying to the specific DOM order) seems to be setting special rules for all the `.rounded-image` elements that follow other 
`.rounded-image` element:

```
.rounded-image {
   display: none;
}
.rounded-image ~ .rounded-image {
   display: block;
}
```

The first selector matches all `.rounded-image` elements, while the second selector matches all `.rounded-image` elements except the first one (that is not preceded by other `.rounded-image` element). So only the first `.rounded-image` element will be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

`:nth-child` means "nth-child of its parent" and not "nth-child among the subset that match the rest of the selector".

`.rounded-image:nth-child(1)` matches elements that are `class="rounded-image"` which are the first child in their parent.

`<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 rounded-image"> </div>` is the second child in its row.

CSS doesn't have any mechanism to test for "nth-child among the subset that match the rest of the selector", you can only achieve that using JavaScript (which you have ruled out).

Comment: Not in a single rule, but technically you can achieve it with two rules if you're looking to only select the first of a class. `.rounded-image { display: none; } .rounded-image ~ .rounded-image { display: block; }` will make the first of its kind hide, while showing any other children with the same class.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to target the first one like this:

```
.rounded-image:nth-child(2) {
  display: none;
}
```

Why? Not sure

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
.rounded-image{
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;  
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    background-image: url('http://placehold.it/234x150');
    background-size: contain; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 118px;
    width:210px;
}

.rounded-image:nth-child(2) {
  display: none;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-12  text-center global-offices">
        <h1>Connect with One of Our Global Offices</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 rounded-image"> </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 Address-lines"> 
         <address>
             <!-- Dublin -->
          <strong>Address</strong><br>
          232 <br>
          10/11 e <br>
          <strong><abbr title="Phone">Phone</abbr></strong> +3530<br>
          <strong><abbr title="Fax">Fax:</abbr></strong> +353
        </address>

      </div>




      <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 rounded-image"> </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6  Address-lines"> 
        <address>
          <!-- Italy -->
          <strong>Address</strong><br>
          Via Marsala I<br>
          Roma<br>
          <strong><abbr title="Phone">Phone</abbr></strong> +370<br>
          <strong><abbr title="Fax">Fax:</abbr></strong> +39
        </address>
      </div>

  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it work, you need to add the class `rounded-image` to all of the sibling elements. The `nth-child` thing doesn't work the way you are assuming, it selects all the childs from its parent element and then selects the `nth-child`. Here is the updated code. Try this.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12  text-center global-offices rounded-image">
          <h1>Connect with One of Our Global Offices</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 rounded-image">hello</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 Address-lines rounded-image">
          <address>
             <!-- Dublin -->
          <strong>Address</strong><br>
          232 <br>
          10/11 e <br>
          <strong><abbr title="Phone">Phone</abbr></strong> +3530<br>
          <strong><abbr title="Fax">Fax:</abbr></strong> +353
        </address>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 rounded-image rounded-image">hello 2</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6  Address-lines rounded-image">
          <address>
          <!-- Italy -->
          <strong>Address</strong><br>
          Via Marsala I<br>
          Roma<br>
          <strong><abbr title="Phone">Phone</abbr></strong> +370<br>
          <strong><abbr title="Fax">Fax:</abbr></strong> +39
        </address>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.rounded-image {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 118px;
  width: 210px;
}

.rounded-image:nth-child(2) {
  display: none;
}
```